# Django - Boolean field returns false in template while true in database

Tags: python, django

Yo ho there, so the issue i'm having is exactly as the title states. In the database, the boolean field can be set as true, but in the template html, it shows up as false.

models.py

```py
class TrainingGoal(models.Model):

    forgeid = models.ForeignKey(ForgeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    strength = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cardio = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    yoga = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.forgeid.forgepass
```

views.py

```py
def profileView(request):
    if not ForgeUser.objects.filter(forgeid=request.user).exists():
        return redirect('profileapp:create')

    forge_user_query = ForgeUser.objects.get(forgeid=request.user)
    training_goal_query = TrainingGoal.objects.filter(forgeid=forge_user_query)


    return render(request, 'profileapp/profile.html', {'forge_profile': forge_user_query, 'training_goals': training_goal_query})
```

abridged profile.html

```html
    {% if training_goals %}
      <div class="goal-container">
        <span class={{training_goals.strength | yesno:"training-true,training-false"}}>STRENGTH</span>
        <span class={{training_goals.cardio | yesno:"training-true,training-false"}}>CARDIO</span>
        <span class={{training_goals.yoga | yesno:"training-true,training-false"}}>YOGA</span>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```

The class value of span tag always shows up as `training-false`, and even expanding it into an if statement shows that the returned value is false. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Are you sure that your fields are returning True? Your default boolean values are 'False'. In your template you can just return the 'training_goals.strength' value in <p> tags to see whether it's true or false as a way of easily debugging.

Comment: Yes, the default value is only for when a new TrainingGoal entry is created. I've changed some of the values to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the query set you're using filter which will return more than one objects. So, you cann't access values using `.<field_name>`

```
training_goal_query = TrainingGoal.objects.filter(forgeid=forge_user_query)
```

Add for loop and it will work fine

```
{% if training_goals %}
{% for goals in training_goals %}
<div class="goal-container">
  <span class={{goals.strength | yesno:"training-true,training-false"}}>STRENGTH</span>
  <span class={{goals.cardio | yesno:"training-true,training-false"}}>CARDIO</span>
  <span class={{goals.yoga | yesno:"training-true,training-false"}}>YOGA</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```